# Hazelcast DotNet client Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, client, hazelcast

I am trying to connect to hazelcast cache server by using the sample code from this [link](https://github.com/asimarslan/hazelcast-dotnet-examples)

But I am getting the below error - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I have verified that the hazelcast cache server is running (in local system). It is running on 5701 port and the same is mentioned C# code.

Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using Hazelcast.Config;
using Hazelcast.Client;
using Hazelcast.Core;
using Hazelcast.IO;
using Hazelcast.IO.Serialization;

namespace Hazelcast.Client.Example
{
    public class ExampleWithCustomSerializer
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
            clientConfig.GetNetworkConfig().AddAddress("127.0.0.1:5701");

            var sc = new SerializerConfig()
                .SetImplementation(new CustomSerializer())
                .SetTypeClass(typeof(Person));

        //Custom Serialization setup up for Person Class
        clientConfig.GetSerializationConfig().AddSerializerConfig(sc);


        IHazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.NewHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        //All cluster operations that you can do with ordinary HazelcastInstance
        IMap<string, Person> mapCustomers = client.GetMap<string, Person>("persons");
        mapCustomers.Put("1", new Person("Joe", "Smith"));
        mapCustomers.Put("2", new Person("Ali", "Selam"));
        mapCustomers.Put("3", new Person("Avi", "Noyan"));

        ICollection<Person> persons = mapCustomers.Values();
        foreach (var person in persons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.ToString());
        }

        HazelcastClient.ShutdownAll();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class CustomSerializer : IStreamSerializer<Person>
{
    public int GetTypeId()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public void Destroy()
    {
        //NOOP
    }

    public void Write(IObjectDataOutput output, Person t)
    {
        byte[] array;
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, t);
            array = ms.ToArray();                
        }

        output.WriteInt(array.Length);
        output.Write(array);
    }

    public Person Read(IObjectDataInput input)
    {
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        var len = input.ReadInt();

        var buffer = new byte[len];
        input.ReadFully(buffer);

        Person result = null;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            result = (Person)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    private string name;
    private string surname;

    public Person(string name, string surname)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }


    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surname; }
        set { surname = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person{ name:" + name + ", surname:"+surname + " }";
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this example with 3.8.1 and it works:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-csharp-client/blob/maintenance-3.x/Hazelcast.Examples/Map/MapCustomSerializerExample.cs